# Cast Laravel query results to class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When creating a query using the syntax `DB::table('foo')`, it creates a generic class (stdClass). Is there any way to cast the resulting rows to a specific class?

Here is some example code that should explain what I want to do:

```
$result = DB::table('foo')->get();
$converted = (Foo) $result; // Not going to work
```

I want to cast all the (stdClass) objects of the array to the Foo class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## As of laravel 5.4

Eloquent models dont have the hydrate() method.

This has been moved to the Eloquent Builder class.

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/search.html?search=hydrate

#### The Eloquent Builder class requires a few things to get this working manually

1. A query builder to initialize
2. A model to hydrate with.

Here is my working example in some laravel 5.8 code:

```
            $instance = new $class;
            $table = $instance->getTable();

            
            $eloquent_builder = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder(
                // the Query Builder!
                DB::connection($connection_name)
                ->table($table)
                ->select($columns)
                ->orderBy($order_by, $order)
            );
            

            // Tell Eloquent what you're using to hydrate the query
            $eloquent_builder->setModel($instance);


            return $eloquent_builder->get();
```

Answer (score 39):

Yes, you can hydrate the results into the classes you want. I found the answer buried deep in a mess of half-answers and confused questions that make up the terrible [Laracasts.com forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-can-i-get-object-with-query-builder-in-laravel). Thanks for asking the question here instead of there.

Once you get the results, hydrate them using your model class:

```
$result = DB::table('foo')->get();
$converted = Foo::hydrate($result);
```

**Edit:** Found some [documentation on the `hydrate` method](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) too, if that helps

**Edit 2:** I found myself in a situation where I needed to cast results from either an `array` or a `collection`, depending on the results of a query. When a collection was returned, it was correctly hydrated, but when the result was an array, they were just `stdClass`. [I wrote a quick method](https://gist.github.com/danken00/3f30af1c700f29227985) added to my master `model` that took a collection of arrays or objects, or a pagination object, and correctly cast it to the object I wanted.

Comment: But what if you use the pagination. E.g.

   $coll = DB::table('Foo')->orderBy('title')->paginate(30);

Then hydration fails ...
Any ideas ?
(Sry - i am new to laravel)

Comment: @derRobert No worries - sometimes in Laravel doing something that seems normal or logical can be very painstaking. Calling `pagination` returns an `AbstractPaginator` object that CONTAINS your results, so they need to be converted within the paginator. My Edit 2 from above links to a function I wrote that does exactly that. Take the `$coll` that you have above, and cast it using my function: `Foo::castResults($coll)`

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd achieve this by setting the PDO Statement fetch_style to PDO::FETCH_CLASS as below

`$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "App\User");`

If you look at the method `Illuminate\Database\Connection::select` you'll see that whilst you can set the fetch_style/fetchMode, you can not the second argument.

```
public function select($query, $bindings = array(), $useReadPdo = true)
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function($me, $query, $bindings) use ($useReadPdo)
    {
        if ($me->pretending()) return array();

        // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
        // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
        // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
        $statement = $this->getPdoForSelect($useReadPdo)->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

        return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());
    });
}
```

Nor can you get access to the statement before fetchAll is called to call `PDOStatement::setFetchMode` for example.

You could perhaps attempt to extend `Illuminate\Database\Connection` and utilise that throughout other Database related classes by extending and replacing where necessary but it seems like a hefty task to maintain.

The other option is to use Eloquent which will give you classes back of a particular type but you get the slight additional overhead of hydrating the model objects.

```
class Foo extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $table = 'foo';
}

Foo::all()
Foo::where('col', 1)->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.8

In the class you want to cast to (`YourClass` in this example) to you'll need constructor like this:

```
    /**
     * Use to initialize fields from DB query like:
     * $query->mapInto(YourClass::class)
     *
     * YourClass constructor.
     * @param \stdClass $data
     */
    public function __construct(\stdClass $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
```

Then in your query:

```
$result = $query
->get()
->mapInto(YourClass::class);
```

$result will now contain a collection of `YourClass` instances with fields loaded from the query.

Comment: Is this better than the accepted solution? Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this page searching for a solution to re-cast a Laravel query to a specific model. In Laravel 7/8 it is possible to cast the result of a query builder to a specific Laravel model which you can then use with eloquent.

You can the `table` method provided by the `DB` facade to begin a query:

```
$query = DB::table('bar');
// You can add table joins, where statements, etc.
```

and then cast the above query to Foo models using:

```
$builder = \App\Foo::select('foo.*');
$builder->setQuery($query);
```

If you use joins etc, you may need to include these on the select. Note that to ensure that foo's id is in the id attribute it needs to be included last.

```
$builder = \App\Foo::select(['baz.*', 'foo.*']);
```

Retrieve the results as a collection of `\App\Foo` Eloquent models as normal.

```
$foos = $builder->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot type cast it this way.
You can build change Your Foo class to get handle of object and work with it.

```
class Foo {
  private $object = null;
  public function __construct(stdClass $object) {
    $this->object = $object;
  }

  public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this->object, $property)) {
      return $this->object->$property;
    }
  }

  public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (property_exists($this->object, $property)) {
      $this->object->$property = $value;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public static function make(stdClass $object) {
    return new self($object);
  }

  public static function makeCollection(array $collection) {
    foreach($collection AS $key => $Item) {
      $collection[$key] = self::make($Item);
    }
    return $collection;
  }
}

$result = DB::table('foo')->get();
$converted = Foo::makeCollection($result);
```

Comment: This won't work because `Builder::get` returns an array of stdClass objects, not a single object. You could iterate over the result set and then apply this to create a new array of results.

Comment: That'll work. For people reading this, remember you'll have the result set twice in memory (in $result and $converted) so don't forget to clear up `$result` and pay attention to selecting large result sets.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, why? PHP's memory management works well (key => zval), it will not create new result set, my code will replace items with it's Foo based class object and return it. It will just replace zval with another and then GC will cleanup unused zval. If I'm wrong, I'll be happy to know explaination why.

Comment: `$result` contains an array of `stdClass` objects, and `$converted` contains an array of `Foo` objects. Both contain the entire result of the query.

Comment: ok, first of all $result references to collection of stdClass object, then we send it to makeCollection, it has iterated the collection that has same references and replaced with new Foo's references, but main result's reference is still the same, stdClass objects are in garbage, then makeCollection returned refernece of $result to $converted. So, $result and $converted have same references. isn't it?
I'm not behind PC, so I cannot check it now, but, I'm happy for discussions. (:

Comment: Thank You @BenSwinburne. It was interesting to analyze this kinds of moments in programming. And thank You for correting my code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. For example:

```
  $query = DB::table('example_tbl')->where('id', $id)->get();
  $cast = (array)$query;
  var_dump($cast);
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specfic. Does this apply to classes as well?

Comment: `Builder::get()` returns an array of objects anyway. `var_dump($query) === var_dump($cast)` here

Comment: yes. But try to see a little more. It will stilll be an object. For you to access the value you will use this "->". But if you cast an array then you can use this "[ ]" to get the value.

Comment: @aldrin27 I have added it to the question

Comment: @Oskar I think you want to pass the variables of your query from a class. Is that right?

Comment: @aldrin27 http://codepad.viper-7.com/4qNsQs the output is already an array of objects as demonstrated here

Comment: @Ben Swinbure Yeah. My bad. I realized that earlier.