# Get instance of Eloquent model from generic DB query in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have models set with different relationships. Let's say my `Entry` model belongs to a `Supplier`, so normally I have a `supplier()` method in my model file.

So far so good, when I have something like `Entry::find(1)->supplier` it works wonderfully. However, what is not working is when I grab entries from a generic DB:: query in Laravel, I obviously cannot access the `supplier()` method because it's not an instance of `Entry`.

```
$entries = DB::table('suppliers')
            ->join('entries', "supplier.id", '=', "entries.supplier_id")
            ->select('entries.*')
            ->where("supplier.name", 'like', "%{$name}%")
            ->get();
```

Now if I `dd($entries)`;

I get results as expected. But when I do something like:

```
dd($entries[0]->supplier); // or ->supplier()
```

I get this error:

> **Undefined property: stdClass::$supplier**.

So how do I *cast* (?) these results to the `Entry` Eloquent model so I can make use of the relationships?

---

This is a `printr` of `$entries`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 0
            [archived] => 0
            [supplier_id] => 5
            [customer_id] => 1
            [contact] => dfgfdg
            [commission] => dfgdfg
            [entrance_date] => 2015-09-22 16:52:33
            [cost_estimate] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [type] => 1
            [watch_id] => 7
            [reference] => dfgdfg
            [serial_number] => 0
            [delivery_date] => 2015-09-07 16:52:33
            [articles_json] => 
            [total_sales_cost_netto] => 
            [gross_profit_netto] => 
            [gross_profit_brutto] => 
            [created_at] => 2015-09-09 20:10:02
            [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 16:52:33
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($entries);`?

Comment: @aldrin27 Added! Thank you.

Comment: I think you should use Eloquent relationships instead of db and joins to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki is right. For you to get the relationship of every foreign keys or primary keys of your tables.

Comment: If you have defined an inverse relation with `belongsTo`, than you would not need to use the generic `DB:table` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Zakaria, just use Eloquent:

```
$entries = Entry::with('supplier')
        ->join('supplier', "supplier.id", '=', "entries.supplier_id")
        ->where("supplier.name", 'like', "%{$name}%")
        ->get();
```

In case you really need to "cast" them,  try something like this:

```
$entries = $yourDbQuery;
$c = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $entryModel = new \App\Entry;
    $c->add($entryModel->forceFill((array)$entry));
}
$c->load('supplier');
```

Comment: I didn't read carefully, but this might also be an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873017/cast-laravel-query-results-to-class